# Creating a Rhombus with numbers in python

Tags: python, numbers

Create a Rhombus through numbers if i input a number it should print the number of lines as same as input number and print the numbers  upto given number, I'm not getting exact solution, Please help me out.

Examples :

If the input is 4

This will be the expected output.

```
       1
     1 2 3
     1 2 3
       1
```

If the input is 5

This will be the expected output.

```
          1
        1 2 3
      1 2 3 4 5
        1 2 3
          1
```

If the input is 7

This will be the expected output.

```
             1
           1 2 3
         1 2 3 4 5
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7
         1 2 3 4 5
           1 2 3
             1
```

I have tried,

```
size = 4
maxlen = len(str(size * size))
m = size * 2 - 1
matrix = [[' ' * maxlen] * m for _ in range(m)]

for n in range(size * size):
     r = n // size
     c = n % size
     matrix[c + r][size - r - 1 + c] = '{0:{1}}'.format(n + 1, maxlen)

print '\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in matrix)
```

But i'm not getting exact solution. Please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pattern_gen(n):
k = n
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        for j in range(0, int(k/2)):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print(j, end="")
        print()
    k = k - 1
k = 1
if n % 2 != 0:
    n = n-1
    k = 2
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        for j in range(0, int(k/2)):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print(j, end="")
        print()
    k = k + 1
```